assign a host to minitest requests
A rails application integrates Devise in its Minitest helpers
module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

However the rails default connection is with www.example.com, while the application requires testing by comparing the result from different host connections.  Hosts are established via  Site class.  sites.yml for example contains
one:
  shop: one
  host: 'www.one.com'
  name: first

two:
  shop: two
  host: 'www.two.com'
  name: second

example:
  shop: id_one
  host: "www.example.com"
  name: localhost

The devise Wiki does not address this matter.
How can the following test
  test "has proper credentials as shop manager" do
    sign_in users(:chain_manager_shop_one)
    get chain_manager_minitests_url(id: shops(:one).id)
    assert_response :success
  end

be written so that both the sign_in and get actions be conducted under a specific host?

The host is irrelevant when using the sign_in helper as it doesn't actually send a request to your application. It uses Wardens built in test helpers to mock the authentication for the next request. If you actually want send a HTTP request to log in the user and it's no different than sending any other request with the Rails integration testing helpers.

With Rails 7, assuredly, the way about this is via this syntax:
get chain_manager_minitests_url(id: shops(:one).id), headers: { "host": 'www.one.com' }
What may have been correct in previous versions of Rails (uncertain which)
    setup do
      request.host = "www.one.com"
    end

does absolutely nothing in Rails 7
